# Is it possible with a VBA macro to always check every cell you just edited, and then coloring it a certain color if its hard coded or a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that, when started, automaticly checks every cell that the user edits, and then colors it a certain color if it is hard coded or a formula.

So far I have tried a combination of "IfThenElse", "IsFormula", "Interior.ColorIndex" and "Worksheet_Change". But I counld not get it to work.

Any recomendations are greatly appriciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in the respective Worksheet's code area. You should adjust the ColorIndexes to your needs.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Select Case True
    Case Target.HasFormula
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        
    Case Target.Value <> ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 12
        
    Case Target.Value2 <> ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
        
    Case Else
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You can implement a flag that is triggered by another macro, if you want to enable and disable the colorization process.